# Nested \xygraph in \xymatrix

Tags: beamer, errors, xy-pic

I am nesting an \xygraph in an \xymatrix like so:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{chemarr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\input xy
\xyoption{all}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\def\pi{a}
\def\emptyline{\vspace{\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{"}

\begin{frame}

\textbf{Reduktion von CI auf C}\\
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{xy}
\xymatrix
{
\ar[r] & _{c_k}\bullet \ar@{-->}[r] \ar@{.>}[r] & \cdots \ar@{-->}[r] & \bullet \ar@{-->}[r] & _{s_k}
\begin{xy}
$
\xygraph{
!{<0cm,0cm>;<1cm,0cm>:<0cm,0.5cm>::}
!{(0,0) }*+{\bullet}="a"
!{(3,0) }*+{(M_k,s_k)}
!{(4,1) }*+{}="b"
!{(4,-1) }*+{}="c"
"a"-"b" "a"-"c" "b"-"c"
}$
\end{xy} \\
}
\end{xy}

\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Additionally I use a global `shorthandoff{"}` to circumvent an error caused by using the  `ngerman` babel package. This displays fine in a `\documentclass{article}`, but everything goes haywire in a `\documentclass{beamer}`. I get errors about missing `}`'s and missing `\end{xy}`'s

What do I have to do to make this nesting work in the beamer class as well?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It is always better to provide a [minimal working example (mwe)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) such that it is possible to compile immediately your code and tell you which could be your problem.

Comment: I get an error only if the `\shorthandoff{"}` declaration is inside the frame. Use `\begin{frame}[fragile]` or make that declaration *before* `\begin{frame}`. Please, turn your code into a complete example that can be run through LaTeX.

Comment: I did use `\shorthandoff{"}` outside of a frame environment and have already tried to use `[fragile]` with no luck. I now updated the code in the original post to be a fully working example - it works now in this single-frame document, but in my main presentation the same errors appear. If I remove this frame from my main presentation, the entire thing compiles without error though.

Comment: As it stands, I don't see how we can answer this. What has to happen to alter the example to give an error: as you say this compiles fine.